# Slurm: by default assign a certain number of GPUs

Tags: slurm

If I do not specify any `--gres=gpu:1` option then the process will use up all GPUs in the compute node.

We only use Slurm for GPU sharing so we would like that every process be assigned one GPU automatically... Is it possible to specify that by default `srun --gres=gpu:1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a default for `--gres` by setting the `SBATCH_GRES` env variable to all users, for instance in `/etc/profile.d` on the login node. Simply create a file in there, that has the following content:

```
export SBATCH_GRES=gpu:1
```

Note that the documentation says

> Note that environment variables will override any options set in a batch script

so people who will want to use more than one, or not use a GPU at all will need to override this default using the command line option, and won't be able to override it with a `#SBATCH --gres` line in their submission script.

Another option would be, to set the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to an empty string for all users by default. Then, in jobs that request GPUs, the variable will be modified by Slurm according to the request, and jobs that do not make the GPU request will not 'see' the GPUs.

If users are likely to play the system (the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable can be overwritten by the users), then you will have to set [cgroups](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html).

Comment: Those are all simple and intelligent solutions to the problem, thank you. By the way, have you heard of the parameter `SallocDefaultCommand` in `slurm.conf`? In an email to a sysadmin I know, she told me she used that parameter to define the default cpu/gpu/etc allocation. But I was unable to find it in recent versions of Slurm, maybe it was in older versions...

Comment: Yes the [release notes for the current (20.11) version](https://slurm.schedmd.com/news.html) mention removal of that option